# How to highlight blockquote tag using css

Tags: html, css

I want the words inside my blockquote to look like they've been highlighted with black using css. I don't know how to do this. Instead, the black forms a large square background behind.

```
blockquote{
color:white;
background:black;}
```

it should look like this:
[image]

Comment: can you more clearly describe what you mean by "highlighted in black"? perhaps mock up a picture for us?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675432/how-to-highlight-syntax-inside-blockquote-tag

Comment: Isn't that what you want? A black background? If not, could you please clarify your question?

Comment: @TarynEast Basically this: http://i.gyazo.com/1336d8536c90ed81bac004d55a8df100.png

Comment: Right, s the problem is your blockquote is a block-level object, not an inline object. so setting the background will set the colour for the whole block (the big square containing the whole thing) not just for behind the text.

Comment: @TarynEast Is there any specific trick I could use to turn it in to an inline object?

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to make some text to be highlighted is to apply `background-color` to a piece of inline text, using something like

```css
.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello this <span class='highlight'>is pluribum text </span> typed randomly</p>
```

You can't really highlight the `blockquote` itself, because it's a block level element and setting its background color will not create the highlight effect. If you want the entire text of a `blockquote` to be highlighted, you have to apply the `highlighted` class to all the text in your `blockquote` so that it remains a block element and its inline content can have a different style

```css
.highlight {
  color:white;
  background:black;
  line-height: 150%;
}
```

```html
Hello testing something Hello testing something Hello testing something Hello testing something Hello testing something Hello testing something Hello testing something
<blockquote><span class="highlight">
 Hello testing something Hello testing something Hello testing something Hello testing something Hello testing something Hello testing something Hello testing something  
</span></blockquote>
 Hello testing something Hello testing something Hello testing something Hello testing something Hello testing something Hello testing something
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, but I wanted to know if there was a way you could do this with css alone without altering the HTML.

Comment: No, because if you make the blockquote inline, it won't be a block element ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:inline;` to the CSS for `.blockquote`.

(I am assuming you created a CSS class called 'blockquote', given that your style declaration has a period in front of that word.  If you meant to apply this to the tag `blockquote`, of course you would remove the period.)

Comment: I actually didn't. :( That was a mistake when typing the code in here. Sorry.